# One-liner for conditional addition in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if time[-2:] == 'PM':
    h = h % 12 + 12
else:
    h = h % 12
```

I would like to reduce the above Python code to something like below:

```
h = h % 12 + (time[:-2] == 'PM') * 12
```

`time` is a string of the form "hh:mm:ss:PM". Can somebody assist me in finding a one-liner for this if-else statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (ternary operator) to get the amount to add. for example:

```
time = '02:30:11 PM'
h = 2
h = h % 12 + (12 if time[-2:] == 'PM' else 0)
print(h)
time = '04:17:54 AM'
h = 4
h = h % 12 + (12 if time[-2:] == 'PM' else 0)
print(h)
```

Output

```
14
4
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, you can use [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Just another example:

```
h = h % 12 + 12 if time[-2:] == 'PM' else h % 12
```

Answer (score 0):

`h = h % 12 + (time[:-2] == 'PM') * 12` will actually work as it is.

If a boolean value is used as an integer, as it's being used here using multiplication, it will represent 1 for True and 0 for False.

Note though, that this latter statement you provided used `time[:-2]` whereas your initial code block used `time[-2:]`, which is want you'll want given the format of `time` that you specified. You can simply replace it in that statement, i.e. `h = h % 12 + (time[-2:] == 'PM') * 12`.

Rather than check the explicit slice of `time`, you could also optimize it to use [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), i.e.
`h = h % 12 + time.endswith('PM') * 12`.

Also, the statement in the else clause can be optimized to `h %= 12`. This wouldn't work for the statement in the if clause or the one-liner though, since the right side of the `%=` operand is evaluated first, e.g. `h %= 12 + 12` would be equivalent to `h %= 24`.